# add new element to array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I do this to query all data from the database

```
$query=$this->db->get('tablename', $num, $offset);
```

I would like to add "string ".$iteratorNumber (that is string1, string2,etc) as a new element in the value array.

I have also tried this

```
$query=$this->db->get('tablename', $num, $offset);
$query=$query->row_array();
$i=0;
foreach($query as $row)
{ 
   array_push($row,"string".i++);
}
```

But this doesn't do what I want it to.

UPDATE
The result looks like this

```
$data = array(
             array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'),
             array('Fred', 'Blue', 'Small'),
             array('Mary', 'Red', 'Large'),
             array('John', 'Green', 'Medium')
             );
```

and I would like to then acquire

```
$data = array(
             array('Name', 'Color', 'Size',''),
             array('Fred', 'Blue', 'Small','something'),
             array('Mary', 'Red', 'Large','something'),
             array('John', 'Green', 'Medium','something')
             );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
$query = $this->db->get('tablename', $num, $offset);
$query[] = "new data here!";
```

Then a new element is added? - If it is an array, you could just do:

```
$query[] = array("data" => "new data here!");
```

Other than the above, I can't think what you can do without seeing even more of your code - but it does add extra data to your outputted array from the database.

**Update**

Maybe I see what you mean now... you want to add 'string X' (where X is the nth entry) as many times as there are rows, so the following should do it (note your question is very nearly there!), but I'd personally make a copy of the array before hand.

```
$query = $copy = $this->db->get('tablename', $num, $offset);
$i=0;
foreach($query as $row){ 
   array_push($copy,"string".i++);
}
$query = $copy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the "&" thingy, It means that you're editing $row and want the changes to last even when foreach is done

```
$query=$this->db->get('tablename', $num, $offset);
$query=$query->row_array();
$i=0;
foreach($query as &$row){ 
   $row[] = "string" . $i++;
   //array_push($row,"string".i++);
}
```

Also, $row[] is faster than array_push, since it has no overhead of calling a function. Use [array_push](http://php.net/array_push) when you want to add like 5 or more elements.